# How to add digital signature and verify in docx4j(Word docx)?

Tags: docx4j

I can found the implemention from apache poi : [apache poi encryption](https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html) , but I can not found from docx4j .

Answer (score 0):

There is an API for handling digital signatures in the commercial [Docx4j Enterprise](https://www.plutext.com/m/index.php/products), but not in docx4j itself.